# MomentJS Issues in React

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I'm having trouble including momentjs in my react app. All the examples I see online show that I can use moment inline as shown where I'm creating the const spreadsheetInfoRow. React complains: "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot call a class as a function" in reference to moment call on that line. If I just use a normal string, it works normally so it's the only part causing an issue in the whole file. Any thoughts?

```
import React from 'react';
import ExcelJS from 'exceljs/dist/es5/exceljs.browser.js'
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'
import moment from 'react-moment';

class SpreadsheetTester extends React.Component {
  async saveAsExcel() {
    const wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook()

    const worksheet = wb.addWorksheet()

    const companyInfoRow = worksheet.addRow(['Title'])
    const spreadsheetInfoRow = worksheet.addRow([`Purchase Stuff as of ${moment()}`])
    const spreadsheetOptionsRow = worksheet.addRow([`There were 2 owners who HAVE ordered something between 4/1/2020 and 4/22/2020.`])
    const headerRow = worksheet.addRow(['Last Order Date', 'Last Name', 'First Name', 'Owner Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip', 'Phone', 'Cell', 'Work Phone', 'Email', 'Bar Code', 'Status'])

    const buf = await wb.xlsx.writeBuffer()

    saveAs(new Blob([buf]), 'abc.xlsx')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.saveAsExcel}>Click Here</button>
    );
  }
}

export default SpreadsheetTester;
```

Comment: You're importing the entire package into your namespace. try using `moment.moment()` instead

Answer (score 2):

You're using it incorrectly. Try this :

```
import Moment from 'react-moment'

let nowDate =  <Moment date={Date.now()}/>;
```

you can now use the `nowDate` variable in the desired location.
Notice the I have used Moment as capital in the import you should do the same . This worked for me.

EDIT:

```
import React from 'react';
import ExcelJS from 'exceljs/dist/es5/exceljs.browser.js'
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'
import Moment from 'react-moment';

class SpreadsheetTester extends React.Component {
  async saveAsExcel() {
    const wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook()

    const worksheet = wb.addWorksheet()
    let nowDate = <Moment date={Date.now()}/>
    const companyInfoRow = worksheet.addRow(['Title'])
    const spreadsheetInfoRow = worksheet.addRow([`Purchase Stuff as of ${nowDate}`])
    const spreadsheetOptionsRow = worksheet.addRow([`There were 2 owners who HAVE ordered something between 4/1/2020 and 4/22/2020.`])
    const headerRow = worksheet.addRow(['Last Order Date', 'Last Name', 'First Name', 'Owner Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip', 'Phone', 'Cell', 'Work Phone', 'Email', 'Bar Code', 'Status'])

    const buf = await wb.xlsx.writeBuffer()

    saveAs(new Blob([buf]), 'abc.xlsx')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.saveAsExcel}>Click Here</button>
    );
  }
}

export default SpreadsheetTester;
```

I have edited your code as well to reflect the necessary changes you can just paste it and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression that it would work normally as long as it was treated as JS. So I thought it would work in the template string or outside of it.

Comment: Your solution actually just spits out generic text to signify it's trying to print an object. Moment components have a ton of data in them. I'll post my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import ExcelJS from 'exceljs/dist/es5/exceljs.browser.js'
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'
import * as moment from 'moment'

class SpreadsheetTester extends React.Component {
  async saveAsExcel() {
    const wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook()

    const worksheet = wb.addWorksheet()

    const companyInfoRow = worksheet.addRow(['Title'])
    const spreadsheetInfoRow = worksheet.addRow([`Purchase Stuff as of ${moment(Date.now()).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}`])
....
```

Comment: I had to import it differently for it to work. Moment object could work, but it's more trouble than it's worth for something this simple in-line.

Answer (score -1):

I tested the `moment` in node and it works fine with the way you're using it. The node `moment` package is exported as a function

However, `react-moment` works a bit differently apparently.
With the 
`"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot call a class as a function"` error message you are getting, it seems like that it's exported as a class.

According to the official doc., `react-moment` should work in this way:

```js
import React  from 'react';
import Moment from 'react-moment';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Moment interval={30000}>
                1976-04-19T12:59-0500
            </Moment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue unfortunately..

```const now = moment(); ...
    const spreadsheetInfoRow = worksheet.addRow([`Purchase Stuff as of ${now}`]) ...
```
"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot call a class as a function" in relation to the line where I assign moment to now

Comment: Why would that not work? Shouldn't the result get evaluated at runtime?

Comment: see my answer thats how you get it to work in react.

Comment: @mmenschig because I misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks @HadiPawar, I have not used MomentJS in React specifically. You're using it as a component, which makes sense.